# Spring MVC: Map to use across multiple classes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dictionary

I am currently using Spring and I have two classes that would like to use the same map. In one class I want to add to the map and in the other I want to remove from the same map. How can I use Spring annotations to achieve this?

Comment: Spring annotations are irrelevant. What is the scope of the map? Is it global, and thus shared by all sessions? If so,put it in a spring bean (which are singletons by default). If each session has its own map, then put it in a session-scoped bean. In both cases, inject that bean where you need it. Make sure your code is thread-safe. What is this map for? Are you sure you shouldn't use the database to store stuff, instead of this map?

Comment: The reason I want to have a map is because I couldn't figure out how to make the interface "ScheduledFuture<V>" injected into a user's session, so that each user could have an object that implements "ScheduledFuture<V" in the user's session. The reason I want to use ScheduledFuture<V> is to have a handle to cancel a task if needed. Is there any way to implement the above? I couldn't figure out a way, so I decided  a Global map would work, which would be shared by all sessions. I created a map bean but when I autowire that bean in to two different classes that use the bean, it shows up as null.

Comment: We can't help you find bugs in your code if you don't post your code.